# Conditional formatting cells based on sum of ajacent text values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet used by multiple users for voting, and want to use conditional formatting to highlight the choices (in column A) based on the results from the rows of answers.

Column 1 is what is being voted on, Row one has the individuals, and then the voting options are yes, no, and maybe. So if option one has all yes answers then it should be highlighted in green. Option two has all no answers, it should be highlighted in red. Option three has a mix of answers it should be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Have you already tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) People are more eager to help if you show some research effort before asking. Otherwise, you will appear as a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). Plus, you should show us some data (screenshot or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest three rules, two with Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

`=COUNTIF($B1:$F1,"N")=5` for Red 
`=COUNTIF($B1:$F1,"Y")=5` for Green and

as the default, Format only cells that contain, Format only cells with: Cell Value greater than =0 for yellow.

[image]