# Special Excel Conditional Formatting - Highlight Row/Column Headers if all proceeding cells are empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a formula that will automatically highlight row or column headers if there is no value in any cell going across the row, or going down a column, but only if there is header text in a row/column. I'm not exactly sure if this can be done, but I've attached a picture of what I'm referring to.

In the example, Column L and R headers are highlighted yellow because there is no "X" in any of the cells descending from the row header. Row 14 and 16 headers are highlighted yellow because there is no "X" going across the cells. Rows 17 and Q are not highlighted, even though they do not have any "x" in their proceeding cells in the row/column, as they do not have any header text. Row Headers are from A-H and Column Headers are from 3-10. The empty cells start at top left corner at K12.

**Example Image**

[image: Example Image]

I'm not sure where to even start for this. Is this possible in excel?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462838/4961700